# SQL Server inner Join with the same table

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a stock table that figure outs my stock list distributed on our company stores storages and on main storage. Now I want to analyze that if I have critical stock at any store (that means less then 5 items) and enough resource in main storage I have to ship item to that stores with a query. I have another subject that I may add new item to main storage, so my query must remind me to sent at least 5 pieces to each store. Also if I opened a new store (I will insert a new row with NULL model, NULL stock to that table) it must list me the needed stock for first day.

Thanks.

(By the way I want to do that in SQL Server 2014 for a personal development not production. I haven't coded any program for last 12 years).

[image: Sample Table]

**Update : 28/08/2017 10:42**

Sorry guys if i couldnt explained my question well. I updated my referance table like that  : dbo.stock

[Referance Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QL2i.png)
And query output like that : 
[Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2MxO.png)

So - I want to check if all stores have company production in their storage, 
And if company opened a new store , i have to find it and have to ship 5 pieces from all products to it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a real sample of the tables and what you have tried so far.

Comment: your post doesn't seem to contain a question, just an incomplete set of statements that describe part of your stock algorithm

Comment: I added my expected output and referance table. And want to describe my question better. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of critical model per store and main resources in stock if any or cero

```
select a.sloc, a.model, a.stock critical, isnull(b.stock,0) 'Main Resources'
from stock a left join stock b on a.model=b.model and b.sloc='Main'
where a.stock<5
```

For the last part of your request, I'm not sure what is needed for a new opened store.

**EDIT**

This procedure does at least what you need, is not optimal, but you can work it up later.

```
begin transaction

declare @initialStock int=5
declare @stockDecrease int=0

insert into stock (sloc, model, stock)
    select (select a.sloc
from stock a 
where a.stock is null) n, m.model, @initialStock
from stock m where m.sloc='Main'  
set @stockDecrease= @@ROWCOUNT/4*@initialStock

delete stock where stock is null

update stock 
set stock=stock-@stockDecrease
where sloc='Main' 

if exists (select 1 from stock where stock<0 and sloc='Main')
    rollback
else
    commit
```

Comment: Hi Horaciux , I updated my question (that section i couldnt explained well). Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you mean when you say ship, describe in detail. Do you want to identify new stores by null values, insert new rows matching items in main sloc (4 models) and update stock in new store and reduce stock in main store?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said.

Comment: See my edit. This transaction is commited only if main stock remains positive, otherwise, it is rolled back

Comment: Thank for that update. Both first and second codes run well but i realised that i am soo poor on sql language. How can i update my crtical stocks after i get the results of first query? If any store has less then 5 item for any model , and i have enough resource on main store , i want to update them.